# Django models INNER JOIN issues

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I get an inner join between two tables unconditionally? 
Having models A,B:

```
class A(models.Model):
    pass

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

When I have a condition I can just write:

```
A.objects.filter(b__pk=1)
```

But how do I generate the following query:

```
SELECT * from A INNER JOIN B ON a.b = b.pk
```

Comment: This the Product-Provider union Product-Customer query is very, very different from the original "inner-join".  Indeed, this product-provider plus product-customer will create a cartesian product between customer and provider.  Do you really want this cartesian product?  What can you possibly do with all those rows?

Comment: @S.Lott: Yes. I wish to select from the result set only those records where customers are in the result of another query and display on my webpage. Practically another JOIN or IN.

Comment: "only those records"?  "result of another query"?  This is why Django uses "navigation' from object to object instead of joins.  Can you be more specific on what data you're getting?

Comment: I changed model names to match the **real** scenario, tried to simplify things. I'll try to explain in words: "Give me all tuples (user,  source, destination) for which destination is in the sources of a given user"

Comment: Please **update** the question with the desired query.  And -- just to keep things simple -- you should delete the silly `A` and `B` example and just focus on the real thing.  "all combinations of Users/Sources/Destinations (all matches)" doesn't seem to square with your comment "user, source, destination for which destination is in the sources of a given user".

Comment: I'll keep this `A/B` example for now as I really want to know how to make a simple INNER JOIN between two tables (I know how to make an OUTER JOIN). Regarding my comment, once I know how to find the cartesian product I can easily filter it by `is in the sources of a given user`

Comment: @"once I know how to find the cartesian product I can easily filter it by is in the sources of a given user"   Except that's totally the wrong thing to do.  You want to get all sources for a user and get just the relevant destinations.  Or something like that.  Please **remove** the incorrect specification of your problem.  Please provide the **correct** specification of your problem so you can get relevant help that actually address your actual problem.

Comment: @S.Lott: I reverted my question to the original formulation as I didn't get an answer for it so far. This is a very specific question that doesn't require questioning my business logic or design.

Comment: I provide a very specific answer that you objected to.  You claimed that the correct answer didn't meet your **real** requirements.  "unmatched records are filtered out by the inner join" sounds like you have some other requirements, not stated in this question, that indicate a faulty design overall.  This question -- as stated -- is quite hypothetical.  The hypothetical answer was unacceptable.  I tried to get past hypothetical into practical.

Answer (score -1):

```
for a in A.objects.all():
    for b in a.b_set.all():
        # you have the joined pair a and b
```

Or

```
for b in B.objects.all():
    for a in b.a.all():
        # you have the joined pair a and b
```

Comment: This way I have to perform many queries. A situation I wish to avoid. What happens if I want to join 3 or more tables?

Comment: @Albert: "This way I have to perform many queries".  Not necessarily.  Check to see what's actually happening.  Django uses a cache.  If you have 3 or more tables, you just "follow" the navigation path.  There's almost no real need for this kind of join logic, however.  If you think you need a JOIN, you're probably not solving the real problem very well.

Comment: Just checked. It performs lots of queries. The first query selects the entire A table which isn't a desired behavior. I will edit the post to better explain my problem.

Comment: @Albert: An inner join **must** select all of a table -- by definition.

Comment: Of course it does. BUT, unmatched records are filtered out by the inner join. Also, the data retrieval is much more efficient when carried out by the DB and not the business logic code.

Comment: @Albert: Again.  There's almost no **real** need for this kind of join logic in a practical web application.